# Can my bike have disk brakes fitted?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, disc-brake

[image]

I just bought this bike and I want to put disk brakes on. I searched on the web for answers but I only could find a bad picture and I couldn't see if it had the same holes at the sane please as my bike. So my question is is my bike able to have disk brakes?

Comment: If you're bound and determined to have them, you can have disk brakes on pretty much any bicycle.  But the bike in the picture is not equipped to take disks, and it would be crazy expensive to add them.  (The lugs in the picture are for fender and rack.)

Comment: An adaptor like http://www.wiggle.co.uk/a2z-universal-disc-mount/ is a lot cheaper than having fittings welded/brazed on. But if the rear triangle isn't strong enough, you would basically have to rebuild the frame.

Comment: Just go for disks on the front forks, getting some new forks for not that much. Most of your braking forces go onto that front wheel; you gain the most from disking-up that one

Answer (score 7):

**No**  Those lugs are for mounting a rear mudguard/fender or a rear rack, not a brake caliper.

They are far too weak for a caliper, too close to the axle and would be torn off quickly by the leverage if you did somehow use them to mount a caliper.

Remember that rear brakes are only 5-10% of your overall braking.  If you desperately want to add discs to this bike, either find a front fork with disc brakes, and a suitable front wheel with a rotor.

Otherwise you need to look out for a newer/better bike.

Comment: Oke thanks for the info i am taking a front diskbrake and for the back the other one

Answer (score 0):

On the front you can replace the fork with a disc fork.  Then you need to buy 1/2 a brake set.  It could get kind of expensive for what you get.

Rear conversion but I still would not recommend it.

[image: hack job]